# How to mix styles from different themes in Android?

Tags: android, material-design

I am new to Android themes, so this is probably a beginners question but I just can't figure it out.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

I want to use the new Material theme, so I used `Theme.Material` with my own colorPrimary and primaryDark colors to get the action bar the way I want it. But for the context menu (the one that opens when you press the 3-dots icon in the top right corner) I want to use the `Theme.Material.Light` version. So I want the context menu with black text on a white background instead of white text on a gray background.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would advise against using the "Material" theme**. It's not supported on older devices. However if you use AppCompat then it will achieve the same effect but with backwards compatibility.

If you create a new Activity using the template it will work as you want. Nevertheless, this is the code:

```
<!--Application-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/NewAppTheme.PopupOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I just tried this solution, but now I don't have an action bar at all! Any suggestions? And how do these overlays work exactly? Nothing is pointing to these overlay styles. Or is it convention to add ".AppBarOverlay" and it will automatically be picked up?

Comment: Oh and good to know that I should use AppCompat, great advice!

Comment: you need to point to the overlay as necessary. E.g. in the toolbar you might add "app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"

Comment: For the action bar question I need to see your code. But you can specify a noaction bar theme in which case you need to set it in the code. See https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Comment: Apparently I had to use AppCompatActivity instead of Activity in order for the action bar to show again!

Comment: I edited your answer with the solution I ended up with and accepted it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add this theme to your Toolbar:

```
app:popupTheme="@style/myStyle"
```

Define backgroundcolor and textColor in your custom theme for the pop-up menu:

```
<style name="myStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">yourBackgroundColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor"yourTextcolor></item>
</style>
```

If you are using ActionBar then use [ActionBar Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and use the generated files in your res folder.

Hope this helps.